# CRC32 Combine How does it work?

Tags: crc, crc32

Can some one please explain me about the working of CRC32 combine which is present in [Zlib library code](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c). I read an excellent article about the working of CRC calculations and usage which is present [here](http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt) from Zlib, but it is silent on combining two CRCs. I would like to know the logic for combining two CRCs.

I tried it out in my code, as it is by copy pasting, but I am not sure what makes it to work.

The code taken from [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c) (as of today) is as below:

```
 #define GF2_DIM 32      /* dimension of GF(2) vectors (length of CRC) */

/* ========================================================================= */
local unsigned long gf2_matrix_times(mat, vec)
    unsigned long *mat;
    unsigned long vec;
{
    unsigned long sum;

    sum = 0;
    while (vec) {
        if (vec & 1)
            sum ^= *mat;
        vec >>= 1;
        mat++;
    }
    return sum;
}

/* ========================================================================= */
local void gf2_matrix_square(square, mat)
    unsigned long *square;
    unsigned long *mat;
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < GF2_DIM; n++)
        square[n] = gf2_matrix_times(mat, mat[n]);
}

/* ========================================================================= */
local uLong crc32_combine_(crc1, crc2, len2)
    uLong crc1;
    uLong crc2;
    z_off64_t len2;
{
    int n;
    unsigned long row;
    unsigned long even[GF2_DIM];    /* even-power-of-two zeros operator */
    unsigned long odd[GF2_DIM];     /* odd-power-of-two zeros operator */

    /* degenerate case (also disallow negative lengths) */
    if (len2 <= 0)
        return crc1;

    /* put operator for one zero bit in odd */
    odd[0] = 0xedb88320UL;          /* CRC-32 polynomial */
    row = 1;
    for (n = 1; n < GF2_DIM; n++) {
        odd[n] = row;
        row <<= 1;
    }

    /* put operator for two zero bits in even */
    gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);

    /* put operator for four zero bits in odd */
    gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);

    /* apply len2 zeros to crc1 (first square will put the operator for one
       zero byte, eight zero bits, in even) */
    do {
        /* apply zeros operator for this bit of len2 */
        gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(even, crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;

        /* if no more bits set, then done */
        if (len2 == 0)
            break;

        /* another iteration of the loop with odd and even swapped */
        gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(odd, crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;

        /* if no more bits set, then done */
    } while (len2 != 0);

    /* return combined crc */
    crc1 ^= crc2;
    return crc1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23126768/1180620).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CRC Calculation Of A Mostly Static Data Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122312/crc-calculation-of-a-mostly-static-data-stream)