# What is the inverse of crc32_combine()'s matrix trick?

Tags: matrix, zlib, checksum, crc

zlib's crc32_combine() takes crcA, crcB, and lengthB to calculate crcAB.

```
# returns crcAB
crc32_combine(crcA, crcB, lenB)
```

Using concepts from Mark Adler's awesome posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122312/crc-calculation-of-a-mostly-static-data-stream/23126768#23126768) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.compression/SHyr5bp5rtc/PP5-pmv9-9sJ) I was able to produce [crc32_trim_trailing.pl](https://github.com/werekraken/crc-trim/blob/6f25f9f8ef2fa4c4dfcaa0c49c628d73e2108a32/script/crc32_trim_trailing.pl) which takes crcAB, crcB, and lengthB to calculate crcA (I use this to peel off padding of a known length and value).

```
# prints crcA
perl crc32_trim_trailing.pl $crcAB $crcB $lenB
```

Unfortunately, this uses the principles of the slow method described, where each null byte must be peeled off one at a time. It's slow, but is a good proof of concept.

I've been working to make a fast version of crc32_trim_trailing which makes use of the matrix trick described in Mark's posts and implemented for the combining use case in zlib's crc32_combine().

Here is my attempt at crc32_trim_trailing.c.

```
/* crc32_trim_trailing.c
  This code is borrows heavily from crc32.c from zlib version 1.2.8, but has
  been altered.
*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define GF2_DIM 32      /* dimension of GF(2) vectors (length of CRC) */

/* ========================================================================= */
unsigned long gf2_matrix_times(mat, vec)
    unsigned long *mat;
    unsigned long vec;
{
    unsigned long sum;

    sum = 0;
    while (vec) {
        if (vec & 1)
            sum ^= *mat;
        vec >>= 1;
        mat++;
    }
    return sum;
}

/* ========================================================================= */
void gf2_matrix_square(square, mat)
    unsigned long *square;
    unsigned long *mat;
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < GF2_DIM; n++)
        square[n] = gf2_matrix_times(mat, mat[n]);
}

/* ========================================================================= */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long crc1;
    unsigned long crc2;
    int len2;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%lx", &crc1);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lx", &crc2);
    sscanf(argv[3],  "%d", &len2);

    int n;
    unsigned long row;
    unsigned long even[GF2_DIM];    /* even-power-of-two zeros operator */
    unsigned long odd[GF2_DIM];     /* odd-power-of-two zeros operator */

    /* degenerate case (also disallow negative lengths) */
    if (len2 <= 0)
        return crc1;

    /* get crcA0 */
    crc1 ^= crc2;

    /* put operator for one zero bit in odd */
    odd[0] = 0x82608edbUL;          /* used sage math to get inverse matrix polynomial */
    row = 1;
    for (n = 1; n < GF2_DIM; n++) {
        odd[n] = row;
        row <<= 1;
    }

    /* put operator for two zero bits in even */
    gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);

    /* put operator for four zero bits in odd */
    gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);

    /* apply len2 zeros to crc1 (first square will put the operator for one
       zero byte, eight zero bits, in even) */
    do {
        /* apply zeros operator for this bit of len2 */
        gf2_matrix_square(even, odd);
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(even, crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;

        /* if no more bits set, then done */
        if (len2 == 0)
            break;

        /* another iteration of the loop with odd and even swapped */
        gf2_matrix_square(odd, even);
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(odd, crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;

        /* if no more bits set, then done */
    } while (len2 != 0);

    printf("\nCRC: %lx\n", crc1);

    return 0;
}
```

I moved the xor to be before the matrix multiplication. This appears to work without issue and gives us crcA0 by xoring crcAB and crcB.

Next, using sage math I was able to find the inverse matrix of the initial matrix used in crc32_combine().

Running each of these matricies through 3 squares results in the matrix crc32_combine() uses to add 1 null byte (matrixA) and it's inverse (matrixB).

Using sage math I confirmed the following.

- matrixA * matrixB = identity
- crc * identity = crc
- crc * matrixA * matrixB = crc

**code:**

```
M = MatrixSpace(GF(2),32,32)
A = M([0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,
1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,
0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,
0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

B = A^-1

I = A*B

print "matrixA"
print A.str()
print "matrixB"
print B.str()
print "identity"
print I.str()

N = MatrixSpace(GF(2),1,32)
THIS=N([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1])

print "'this' crc * identity"
print THIS * I
print "'this' crc * maxtrixA"
print THIS * A
print "'this' crc * maxtrixA * matrixB"
print THIS * A * B
```

**output:**

```
matrixA
[0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
matrixB
[1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
identity
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
'this' crc * identity
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
'this' crc * maxtrixA
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0]
'this' crc * maxtrixA * matrixB
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
```

I tested gf2_matrix_times() using a crc and the identity matrix which as expected resulted in no change to the crc.

Since gf2_matrix_times(crc, matrixA) can be used to add 1 null byte to the crc, I had hoped gf2_matrix_times(crc, matrixB) could be used to remove 1 null byte. However, this does not appear to work out of the box.

Additionally, crc * matrixA in sage math produces a different result (0xc05e2dda) than crcA0 (0xa5f45be9) in crc32_combine() when lengthB is 1.

Why is there disparity in GF(2) matrix multiplication between sage math and gf2_matrix_times()?
Why does gf2_matrix_times(crc, matrixB) not reverse gf2_matrix_times(crc, matrixA) when matrixA and matrixB are inverse?

Comment: If anyone is interested in a fast crc32_trim_trailing(), I published this [library](https://github.com/werekraken/libcrc32trim).

Comment: A CRC can be cycled forwards|backward n bits multiplying it by pow(2, +|-n)%poly, which can be implemented using exponentiation by squaring for O(log(n)) time complexity, or a table of pow(2, +|-i)%poly for i = 1 to n can be generated reducing the time complexity to O(1). The multiply is also mod poly. Example code for cycling a CRC backwards is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657385/54660846#54660846) ,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will begin by looking at a simple bit-wise implementation of the standard CRC-32 (to be a self-contained definition of the CRC, this routine returns the initial CRC, i.e. the CRC of the empty string, when `data` is `NULL`):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define POLY 0xedb88320

uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc, void const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *(unsigned char const *)data++;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
    }
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

We can simplify that for applying `n` zeros to a CRC:

```
uint32_t crc32_zeros(uint32_t crc, size_t n) {
    crc = ~crc;
    while (n--)
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

Now let's look carefully at the application of single zero bit to the CRC:

```
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
```

There are two paths that could have been taken when applying the bit. In the last operation, either the polynomial was exclusive-ored with the CRC, or it wasn't. If we want to reverse this, we would like to know which way it went.

We can tell by looking at the high bit of the result. We can see that if the polynomial was not exclusive-ored, then the high bit must be 0. But what if it was exclusive-ored? In that case, the high bit of the result is the high bit of `POLY`. We can see that that high bit is 1. So we can tell just by looking at the high bit of the result. In fact, this must be the case for any valid CRC polynomial, since all have the coefficient 1 for the x<sup>0</sup> term. (That term is in the high bit for this reflected polynomial.)

By inspection we can easily reverse that operation, where here `crc` going in is the final CRC after applying a 0 bit, and `crc` coming out is what that CRC was before applying the 0 bit:

```
crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? ((crc ^ POLY) << 1) + 1 : crc << 1;
```

That will take a final CRC and reverse the action of computing the CRC over a single 0 bit. Note that we have to insert the low 1 bit that would have caused the exclusive-or, for that case.

We can factor out `POLY` to get:

```
crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ ((POLY << 1) + 1) : crc << 1;
```

That is exactly the same as the operation to *append* a 0 bit to a *non*-reflected CRC with the polynomial `(POLY << 1) + 1`, which is just `POLY` rotated left one bit.

We can then write a function to remove `n` zero bytes from a standard CRC-32:

```
#define UNPOLY ((POLY << 1) + 1)

uint32_t crc32_remove_zeros(uint32_t crc, size_t n) {
    crc = ~crc;
    while (n--)
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ UNPOLY : crc << 1;
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

Now we can use the same approach as used in zlib, but with a non-reflected CRC, to write a function to remove *n* zeros from a CRC-32 in O(log(*n*)) time. We do not need to invert any matrices, since we have already inverted the original operation.

The remainder is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks for taking the time to respond. I worked on this some more and was able to get it [working](https://github.com/werekraken/crc-trim/blob/f6bd179864f91ed64ade72e29da7c0e53165a695/crc32_trim_trailing.c).

Comment: Good. I see that you now got the correct polynomial, `0xdb710641`. That's `(POLY << 1) + 1`.