# calculating the CRC on the fly, possible or not

Tags: hash, crc, crc32

Is it possible to calculate the CRCs on the fly (in the streams)?

For example, I have 1-gigabyte data and I want to reduce the possibility of undetected errors.
I want to implement something (CRC or Hash) over the whole file,
(I already have implemented CRCs for each chunk, which contains some packets),

When we put a CRC over the whole file, is it possible to start calculating the CRC as soon as we have the first packet or do we have to wait for the whole file to be received and then start calculating the CRCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. CRCs and every hash I know of are all streamable. They have a small, finite state that is updated as data is fed through them. For CRCs, the state is the CRC itself.

The CRC in zlib takes this form:

```
unsigned long crc32(unsigned long crc, const unsigned char *buf, unsigned len);
```

When `buf` is `NULL`, the initial CRC is returned. So it is used like this:

```
unsigned long crc = crc32(0, NULL, 0);    // initial CRC
for (...) {                               // some sort of loop
    ...                                   // generating a chunk of data
    crc = crc32(crc, buf, len);           // update the CRC with the data
    ...                                   // this all gets repeated many times
}
...                                       // loop is done, crc has the CRC
```

Comment: But to ensure the integrity of the data, we need to wait until we have the last packet and update the state of the CRC. Is that right?

Comment: @Arash - correct. Using a single CRC for 1 gigabyte of data would require having to retransmit the entire 1 gigabyte of data. Splitting up the data into smaller parts, with a CRC for each part would make more sense. If the error rate and message size combine such that a significant number of retransmissions would occur, then an error correcting code would make more sense than a CRC.

Comment: You can do both. You can compute CRCs on packets of data, as well as compute a CRC on the whole thing. The latter helps assure that you have all of the packets, and that they are in the correct order. It takes practically no more compute time, using for example `crc32_combine()` in zlib.

Comment: This is very useful when we want to save time. Why don't people use it? Can you name some of the applications that they actually calculate CRCs on the fly?

Comment: All of them, as far as I know. In general you want to avoid storing an entire file in memory. You may not even have that much memory. So the processing streams the data, requiring calculating CRCs a chunk at a time.

Comment: You are right, when we are doing CRC on the fly we actually don't need to load the whole file in memory, we can simply compute and update the CRC checksums as soon as we get a new chunk and when we have the last packet compare it with the sender. so I wonder why people are not a fan of this on the fly method.

Comment: @MarkAdler Where I can find this crc32() function in detail? I saw this link https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c but I couldn't figure out how CRC is calculated.

Comment: @Arash Not for comments -- ask a new question.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515573/crc32-function-explanation-with-regards-to-data-streams