# crc32 function explanation with regards to data streams

Tags: crc

Where I can find this crc32() function in detail? I saw this [Link](http://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c) but I couldn't figure out how CRC is being calculated.
I asked a question about updating the CRC based on the data stream instead of waiting to have all the data. I got the answer as follows (Thanks to @MarkAdler):

```
unsigned long crc = crc32(0, NULL, 0);    // initial CRC
for (...) {                               // some sort of loop
    ...                                   // generating a chunk of data
    crc = crc32(crc, buf, len);           // update the CRC with the data
    ...                                   // this all gets repeated many times
}
...                                       // loop is done, crc has the CRC
```

1. Can you please be more specific about the `crc32()` function?
2. Is there any pseudo code for that function which explains it?
3. And `for` loop here is for getting data right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. More specific how?
2. Do you want an explanation of how to use it, or how it works internally? How it works internally is in the source code you linked.
3. Yes. You would get chunks of data from wherever, and feed them through `crc32()` to get the CRC-32/ISO-HDLC of the entire stream of data.

As for the source code you linked, that was not written to teach anyone about how CRC's work. It was written to be fast. Here is a simple, but slow (one bit at a time), CRC routine in C, that may, or may not, help you with what you're looking for:

```
uint32_t crc32iso_hdlc_bit(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

(That code was generated by [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany).)

If you would like to learn more about CRCs, start [here](https://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I mean how the CRC gets updated every time new data comes in. How it `xor` the Data? (you probably have it on the code but can you explain it please) and what is the `len` in the function?

Comment: `len` is the number of bytes at the location `mem` to process.

Comment: For how the CRC is updated, you can look at the short function I posted in the answer to see what it does. (In C, `^` is exclusive-or.) To _understand_ what it does, read the tutorial at the last link in my answer.

Comment: Thank you I am going to read that. can you explain this line too? `crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;` What second for loop doing exactly?

Comment: You'll need to read the tutorial for that. It's dividing the message polynomial by the CRC polynomial, over the Galois-Field(2), to get the remainder.

Comment: Can I ask a quick question, please? If we have 4 packets that are creating a file (CRC is computed over a file) as soon as we have packet 1 we start the process of computing the CRC and updating the CRC state. If we receive packets 1,2,4 but not 3 we can't continue the process and should wait for packet 3 right?

Comment: There is a way to combine CRCs. See `crc32combine()` in zlib. So you could compute the CRC of 1, 2, 3, and 4, individually, and then combine them later.

Comment: Without adding 0s?

Comment: Did you look at it? It rapidly computes the effect of adding zeros without adding zeros.