# Parallel CRC32 in C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, checksum, crc, crc32

I am trying to implement CRC32 calculation of file by splitting it in parts. I used algorithms and ideas from [CRC Calculation Of A Mostly Static Data Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122312/crc-calculation-of-a-mostly-static-data-stream/23126768#23126768).
Unfortunately, my program gives incorrect answer, although it returns the same value of CRC regardless of number of parts.
Please, tell me where the mistake is and what I do wrong.
Here is the code of program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pthread.h>


using namespace std;

struct data {
    
    pthread_t id;
    uint8_t *buf;
    long int start, end;
    long int num_zeros;
    uint32_t crc;
        
    
};


//Straight function
uint32_t crc_32(ifstream& input) {
    
    input.seekg(0, input.end);
    size_t size = input.tellg();
    input.seekg(0, input.beg);
    
    
    uint32_t polynomial = 0xEDB88320;
    uint32_t table[256];
    
    
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<=0xff; i++) {
        
        
        
        uint32_t c = i;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            if (c & 1) {
                c = polynomial ^ (c >> 1);
            }
            else {
                c >>= 1;
            }
        }
        table[i] = c;
        
    }
    
    uint32_t CRC = 0xffffffff;
    
    uint8_t buf;
    
    
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
        
        
        
        input.read( (char *) &buf, sizeof(buf));
        CRC = (CRC>>8) ^ table[(CRC ^ buf) & 0xff ];
        
    }
    
    CRC ^= 0xffffffff;
    
    return CRC;
    
    
}

// generate crc 

uint32_t GenCrc(data *work, long int beg, long int end, uint32_t *crctbl) {
    uint32_t init = 0x00000000;
    
    
    for(long int i = beg; i<end; i++) {
        
        init = (init<<8)^crctbl[ (init>>24) ^ work->buf[i] ];
        
    }
    
    
    return init;
    
}




// (a*b)%crc 
uint32_t MpyModCrc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    
    uint32_t pd = 0;
    uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        pd = (pd<<1)^((0-(pd>>31))&0x04c11db7);
        pd ^= (0-(b>>31))&a;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return pd;
    
}


// pow(2,p)%crc 
uint32_t PowModCrc(uint32_t p) {
    uint32_t prd = 0x1u;                    
    uint32_t sqr = 0x2u;                    
    while(p) {
        if(p&1)
            prd = MpyModCrc(prd, sqr);
        
        sqr = MpyModCrc(sqr, sqr);
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}




void do_work(data *work) {
    
    //Generate lookup table:
    uint32_t polynomial = 0x04c11db7;
    
    uint32_t crctbl[256];
    uint32_t crc;
    uint32_t c;
    uint32_t i;
    
    for(c=0; c <256; c++) {
        
        crc = c<<24;
        /*
        for(i=0; i <8; i++) {
            
            if( (crc & 0x80000000) !=0) {
                crc <<= 1;
                crc ^= polynomial;
            }
            else {
                crc <<=1;
            }
        }
        */
        
        for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
            crc = (crc<<1)^(0-(crc>>31))&polynomial;
        }
        
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
    
    
    
        
    uint32_t pmc;
    uint32_t crf;
    
    
    crf = GenCrc(work, work->start, work->end, crctbl);
    
    if(work->num_zeros > 0) {
    
        pmc = PowModCrc((work->num_zeros)*8);
        crf = MpyModCrc(crf, pmc);
    }
    
    work->crc = crf;

}






void *do_stuff(void *d) {
    
    data *mydata = (data*)d;
    do_work(mydata);
    
    return 0;
    
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {



ifstream input("8733718.zip", ios::binary);

if(!input) {
    cerr << "Can't open file." <<endl;
    
}


input.seekg(0, input.end);
long int len = input.tellg();
input.seekg(0, input.beg);



uint8_t *buf = new uint8_t[len];

input.read( (char *) buf, len);

int k;
cout << "Enter number of parts: ";

if(!(cin >> k) || k<1) {
    cout << "Error. We need at least one part!" <<endl;
    return -1;
}


data *work = new data[k+1];

for(int i=0; i < k; i++) {
    
    work[i].start = len*i;
    work[i].start /=k;
    
    work[i].end = len * (i+1);
    work[i].end /= k;
    
    work[i].num_zeros = len - work[i].end;
    work[i].buf = buf;
    
}

for(int i=0; i < k; i++) {
    
    void *tmp = (void*)&work[i];
    pthread_create(&work[i].id, 0, do_stuff, tmp);
    
}

for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
    pthread_join(work[i].id, 0);
}


uint32_t crc = work[0].crc;


for(int i=1; i<k; i++) {
    crc ^= work[i].crc;
}

delete [] buf;
delete [] work;









cout << "Straigth CRC_32 = ";
uint32_t result;
result = crc_32(input);
cout << hex << result;
cout <<endl <<endl;


cout << "Parallel CRC_32 = ";
uint32_t result2;
result2 = crc;
cout << hex << crc <<endl <<endl;

cout <<endl <<endl;
cout <<"=========================="<<endl<<endl;

input.close();

    return 0;
}
```

"Straight" function gives the answer which coincides with the answer of, for example, website https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/crc32_checksum.html.
But "parallel" procedure gives another answer.

Comment: I don't find it credible that you can multi-thread a CRC calculation. Every step depends on the result of the prior step. I also fail to see the motivation.

Comment: CRC is perfectly parallizable because it's an affine transformation.

Comment: It is possible to split the input into chunks, compute a CRC of each chunk, and combine those results into a CRC for the whole input.  However, the "combine those results" step is considerably more complicated than just XORing them together.  The answers to the question you linked already discuss this, so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: In my code I took into consideration that I should XOR not A, but A00..000. Unfortunately, something goes wrong at this step and I can not figure out what I should change to make it work right.

Comment: My intention was to calculate on first step CRC32 of A000, then on the next step CRC32 of 0B00, on the third step - CRC32 of 00C0 etc. and then XOR it all.

Comment: I'm not sure yet why your code is not working, but I do question whether it's a useful thing to do.  I anticipate that the serial computation will be I/O bound, and parallelizing it definitely does not reduce the I/O cost.  Parallelization does, however, add thread-management and algorithmic overhead. Plus, you have to load the whole file into memory at once, which a CRC computation ordinarily would not do.  I can't rule out the possibility that you would see *some* speedup, but I am skeptical about seeing enough speedup to be worthwhile.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried it and found that, at least on my machine, there is a benefit. When purging the operating system's disk buffers each time, I got a factor of 6.4 speedup over a serial calculation. Letting the disk buffers operate normally, I got a factor of 6.8 speedup. It did appear CPU bound in the latter case, with about 850% utilization. This was on a 450 MB file, using an eight-or-so-core Apple M1 processor, and a 10 GB/s SSD.

Comment: @MarkAdler -  I tested a 1GB (2^32) block of ram on a 4 core laptop. With a table based CRC, 1 thread 1.8 seconds (555MBPS), 8 threads 0.25 seconds (4 GBPS). With PCLMULQDQ, 1 thread 0.064 seconds (15.625 GBPS), 8 threads 0.032 seconds (31.25 GPBS).

Comment: Sure, from RAM there would be a benefit. John Bollinger's conjecture was that a CRC calculation would be I/O bound when reading from mass storage, so multiple cores wouldn't help.

Comment: @MarkAdler - that would depend on the device. Sata HDD max at less than 150 MBPS. USB SDD at around 550 MBPS. If buffering wasn't enough to overlap I/O with CRC calculation, two threads, one for I/O, one for CRC would be enough for these type of devices. At the other extreme, a 10 GBPS NVMe SDD, would benefit, unless PCLMULQDQ based CRC was used. I think the max for a PC would be a Raid controller using multiple high end NVMe SSDs, something like 32 GBPS based on number of lanes available with PCIE interface.

Answer (score 2):

As rcgldr noted, you are mixing up reflected and non-reflected CRC calculations. The original CRC is reflected so you need to stick with that. You need to always be shifting *right*. You always need to use the reflected polynomial, as in the original, `0xedb88320`.

So, `GenCRC()` needs to shift right, and use the low eight bits of the CRC (which you're calling `init`) instead of the high eight bits to get the index.

`MpyModCrc()` needs to shift right, use the low bit instead of the high bit for the decisions, and use the correct polynomial.

`PowModCrc()` is starting off with the wrong initial polynomials. Since the polynomials are reflected, the initial values need to be as well. So 1 (*x*<sup>0</sup>) is `0x80000000`, and *x* (*x*<sup>1</sup>) is `0x40000000`.

In `do_work()`, you need to generate the table exactly as you did `crc_32()`. Of course, why you're generating the exact same table in every thread, I have no idea. Do that once.

Lastly, having done all that, your threads will be computing the CRC with a zero initial value and zero final exclusive or. That's ok, so long as you then exclusive-or with the CRC of `len` zero bytes with an initial value of `0xffffffff`, and then exclusive-or the final result with `0xffffffff` to get the same effect. That is:

```
   crc ^= MpyModCrc(0xffffffff, PowModCrc(len * 8)) ^ 0xffffffff;
```

Alternatively, you could start the first work unit, and only that one, with an initial CRC of `0xffffffff`. And then exclusive-or the final result with `0xffffffff`.

Another improvement is to not calculate the CRC of so many zeros (even though it is an O(log n) calculation), and to only calculate the power function once. You can combine the CRCs as you join each thread, only needing `PowModCrc()` of your chunk size, calculating that just once, and applying it each time. And once more for the final chunk which may be smaller.

You don't need to read in the entire file and then do the CRC calculation. You should be calculating in parallel with reading. Instead of deciding how many pieces, decide on a fixed chunk size. Then read chunks and fire off threads for CRC calculations as you read them. Combine the CRCs as the threads complete, joining them in order. Limit the number of threads to something like twice the number of cores. You want to keep the cores busy, but you don't want the overhead of too many threads and too much memory in use.

The final alternative would be to not do any of this, and simply use [zlib](https://zlib.net) which provides the [CRC combination functions](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h#L1750) for you.

Comment: You happen to be using the same CRC that zlib does. You can also use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate CRC functions and CRC combination functions for any CRC definition.

Answer (score 1):

crc_32() is a right shifting CRC that initial CRC = 0xffffffff and final CRC ^= 0xffffffff, while do_work() gencrc(), ... are using a left shifting CRC.

Change do_work() and gencrc() to be a modified version of crc_32() with initial CRC = 0, and final CRC not changed.

Changes for CRC32 (which is a reflected CRC):

```
#define CRCPOLY  0xEDB88320u
#define INITXOR  0xFFFFFFFFu
#define FINALXOR 0xFFFFFFFFu

static uint32_t crc_table[256];

void GenCrcTable()
{
uint32_t crc;
    for (uint32_t byte = 0; byte <= 0xFFu; byte++ )
    {
        crc = byte;
        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++ )
            crc = (crc&1) ? (crc>>1)^CRCPOLY : (crc>>1);
        crc_table[byte] = crc;
    }
}

int Crc32(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t crc = INITXOR;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        crc = crc_table[(crc&0xFFu)^*buffer++]^(crc>>8);
    crc ^= FINALXOR;
    return crc;
}

// use this one for the multi-thread code    
int Crc320(uint8_t *buffer, size_t length)
{
    uint32_t crc = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        crc = crc_table[(crc&0xFFu)^*buffer++]^(crc>>8);
    return crc;
}

// carryless multiply modulo crc
uint32_t MpyModCrc(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) // (a*b)%crc
{
uint32_t prd = 0;
uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        prd  = (prd&1u) ? (prd>>1)^CRCPOLY : (prd>>1);
        prd ^= (b&1u)   ? a : 0;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}

// exponentiate by repeated squaring modulo crc
uint32_t PowModCrc(uint32_t p)          // pow(2,p)%crc
{
uint32_t prd = 0x80000000u;             // current product
uint32_t sqr = 0x40000000u;             // current square
    while(p){
        if(p&1)
            prd = MpyModCrc(prd, sqr);
        sqr = MpyModCrc(sqr, sqr);
        p >>= 1;
    }
    return prd;
}
```

After these changes try this code at the end (I haven't tested this yet):

```
    uint32_t crc = work[0].crc;
    for(int i=1; i<k; i++) {
        crc ^= work[i].crc;
    }
    uint32_t pmc = PowModCrc(len*8);         // add initial CRC of 0xffffffff
    crc ^= MpyModCrc(0xffffffff, pmc);
    crc ^= 0xffffffff;                       // final_xor = 0xffffffff
```

---

If running on a PC in 64 bit mode, you could use a PCLMULQDQ based CRC to speed things up (probably to the point that multi-threading won't help much). You can search github for examples of this. The assembly files are a bit over 500 lines. I have 6 sets of these for Visual Studio | MASM (ML64.EXE). Link to to code for 32 bit CRC reflected. If using my code, you need to change the `if` defines from 0 to 1 to use CRC32 instead of CRC32C.

https://github.com/jeffareid/crc/tree/master/crc32r

Comment: Even better, on ARM there is an instruction for CRC-32. Which, by the way, makes me wonder why you even calculate a CRC-32C in your PCLMULQDQ code. If the Intel processor has that instruction, it also has a CRC-32C, which is faster still.

Comment: @MarkAdler - that was done to keep all 6 sets similar, each set  with conditionals to choose between two polynomials.

Comment: @MarkAdler  - I ran into a Visual Studio 2015|2019 quirk. In a Windows console X64 project, setting linker system option /LARGEADDRESSAWARE is supposed to get past the 2GB limit for an array, but using new operator generates compiler error array to large if trying to allocate an array larger than 2GB. However, malloc() doesn't have this issue. I was able to allocate a 16GB array with 32GB of ram on my older desktop.