# CRC32 of an appended block

Tags: crc32

I'm computing CRC32 in a rolling fashion on the contents of a file. If the file has 3 blocks ABC, CRC32 is computed linearly `CRC(CRC(CRC(A, 0xffffffff), B), C)`. This is done with code that looks like:

```
uint32_t crc32(unsigned char const *buf, uint32_t buf_size, uint32_t crc32) {
     for (int i = 0; i < buf_size; i++)
         crc32 = (crc32 >> 8) ^ table[(crc32 ^ buf[i]) & 0xff];
     return crc32;
 }
```

Even though I write entire content ABC at once, computing the CRC as above(which gets verified at the server), read is normally done on a specific block. So, I would like to track CRC32 of each individual block as it is written.

Based on my limited understanding of how CRC32 polynomial works,

```
A mod G  = CRC1
AB mod G = CRC2
```

If I want CRC32 of B, I'm thinking following should do the trick:

```
(CRC2 - CRC1) mod G  
or
(CRC2 ^ CRC1) mod G
```

Of course, following code doesn't work.

```
uint32_t
crc32sw_diff(uint32_t crc1, uint32_t crc2)
 {
     uint32_t delta = crc1 ^ crc2;
     return crc32(&delta, 4, 0xffffffff);
 }
```

Other option is probably to compute CRC32 of individual blocks and combine it with something like [zlib's crc32_combine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122312/crc-calculation-of-a-mostly-static-data-stream/23126768#23126768) to get CRC32 of entire file.

Comment: What's wrong with your "other option"?

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just happen to stumble upon it when my 'diff' method didn't work and was just curious how to fix the diff.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you're trying to do. Do you want the CRC of `B`, given the CRCs of `A` and `AB`?

Comment: Correct. Likewise, given the CRC of AB and ABC, I would like to get the CRC of C and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122312/crc-calculation-of-a-mostly-static-data-stream/23126768#23126768) for how CRC combination works. `CRC(A) ^ CRC(B)` is not equal to `CRC(AB)`. However (for pure CRCs) using the notation that `AB` is the concatenated message of `A` followed by `B`, and `0` meaning an equal length message will all zeros, then `CRC(A0) ^ CRC(0B)` *is* equal to `CRC(AB)`.

This also means that `CRC(A0) ^ CRC(AB)` == `CRC(0B)`. Since `CRC(0B) == CRC(B)` (feeding zeros doesn't change a pure CRC), you can find it using `crc32_combine()` from [zlib](https://zlib.net/).

So, `crc32_combine(crca, crcab, lenb)` will return `crcb`.